# SQL to combine data from fields and provide collatted data

Tags: python, mysql, sql, case

I have the following data in a single table. vc is varchar

```
eq_time                 eq_latitude eq_longitude    eq_depth    eq_mag  eq_magType  eq_nst  eq_gap  eq_dmin     eq_rms  eq_net  eq_id       eq_updated              eq_place                                    eq_type
timestamp               double      double          double      double  vc(20)      double  double  double      double  vc(100) vc(20)      timestamp               vc(100)                                     vc(20)
"2015-02-19 06:32:53"   33.9585     -116.9558333    12.35       0.74    ml          16      72      0.1357      0.22    ci      ci37318664  "2015-02-19 06:36:54"   "4km NNE of Beaumont     California"        earthquake
"2015-02-19 06:07:18"   38.7946663  -122.7791672    3.78        0.55    md          6       161     0.01831     0       nc      nc72397170  "2015-02-19 06:41:05"   "2km NW of The Geysers   California"        earthquake
"2015-02-19 06:07:04"   38.7923317  -122.7785034    3.75        1.01    md          20      74      0.007406    0.03    nc      nc72397165  "2015-02-19 06:51:05"   "2km NW of The Geysers   California"        earthquake
"2015-02-19 06:03:26"   -4.9889      101.8933       31.96       4.6     mb          0       179     1.229       0.83    us      usc000tre3  "2015-02-19 06:51:21"   "137km SSW of Bengkulu   Indonesia"         earthquake
"2015-02-19 05:59:26"   38.5807     -118.4577       5.63        1.44    ml          10      193.63  0.621       0       nn      nn00483562  "2015-02-19 06:02:59"   "15km ENE of Hawthorne   Nevada"            earthquake
"2015-02-19 05:55:55"   65.8149     -149.7911       0.1         1.6     ml          0       0       0           0.88    ak      ak11512985  "2015-02-19 06:30:52"   "98km NNE of Manley Hot Springs  Alaska"    earthquake
"2015-02-19 05:52:44"   38.8250008  -122.8448334    2.31        0.57    md          8       167     0.007886    0.01    nc      nc72397155  "2015-02-19 06:23:03"   "9km NW of The Geysers   California"        earthquake
"2015-02-19 05:45:02"   35.5811667  -118.474        9.46        0.71    ml          13      86      0.08144     0.12    ci      ci37318648  "2015-02-19 05:49:06"   "2km ESE of Bodfish  California"            earthquake
"2015-02-19 05:39:25"   35.8693 -    116.6933       7           0.41    ml          6       274.08  0.196       0       nn      nn00483561  "2015-02-19 05:41:23"   "65km E of Searles Valley    California"    earthquake
"2015-02-19 05:36:57"   35.9223328  -120.4726639    5.29        2.37    md          41      46      0.02433     0.07    nc      nc72397150  "2015-02-19 06:02:03"   "26km SSW of Coalinga    California"        earthquake
```

Similarly, there are 8700 rows. I want to find out the occurences per week per magnitude range. The final data should look as follows.

```
Week    2-2.99  3-3.99  4-4.99  5-5.99
1       10      2       4       6
2       1       3       0       8
3       9       1       7       1
4       7       9       1       0
```

I have tried the following query, but I am missing a lot of data.

```
SELECT rs.eq_week
FROM (
    SELECT CASE 
        WHEN eq_mag between 2 and 2.99
            THEN 'Week 1'
    from usaeq) RS
Group By rs.eq_week
```

Comment: What is the syntax of the comma for `between`?  That is not valid SQL.  Second, what are the data types of the columns?  Third, how are you defining "week"?  Your data doesn't seem to have a column with this name.

Comment: @GordonLinoff.. I have updated the question, edited my query. Still I am not sure of the way `case` works. I am consider week as a 7 day period. For example Week1 is 2015-02-19 00:00:00 to 2015-02-26 23:59:59

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.

```
select 
    week, count(mag2) as mag2, count(mag3) as mag3, count(mag4) as mag4, count(mag5) as mag5
from
    ((select 
        case
                when date(eq_time) between cast('2015-01-20' as date) and cast('2015-01-26' as date) then 1
                when date(eq_time) between cast('2015-01-27' as date) and cast('2015-02-02' as date) then 2
                when date(eq_time) between cast('2015-02-03' as date) and cast('2015-02-09' as date) then 3
                when date(eq_time) between cast('2015-02-10' as date) and cast('2015-02-16' as date) then 4
                when date(eq_time) between cast('2015-02-17' as date) and cast('2015-02-23' as date) then 5
                when date(eq_time) between cast('2015-02-24' as date) and cast('2015-02-29' as date) then 6
            end week,
            usaeq.eq_id
    from
        usaeq) as week, (select 
        case
                when eq_mag between 2 and 2.99 then eq_mag
            end mag2,
            usaeq.eq_id
    from
        usaeq) as mag2, (select 
        case
                when eq_mag between 3 and 3.99 then eq_mag
            end mag3,
            usaeq.eq_id
    from
        usaeq) as mag3, (select 
        case
                when eq_mag between 4 and 4.99 then eq_mag
            end mag4,
            usaeq.eq_id
    from
        usaeq) as mag4, (select 
        case
                when eq_mag >= 5 then eq_mag
            end mag5,
            usaeq.eq_id
    from
        usaeq) as mag5)
where
    week.eq_id = mag2.eq_id and
    week.eq_id = mag3.eq_id and
    week.eq_id = mag4.eq_id and
    week.eq_id = mag5.eq_id 
group by week;
```

After running the query, the data looks as follows.

```
week mag2 mag3 mag4 mag5
1    259  69   129  19
2    315  162  132  41
3    286  94   87   19
4    259  64   83   27
5    59   11   26   17
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a easy way, although the column headers are not quite as in your example:

```
TRANSFORM Count(eq.eq_time) AS Count_occur
SELECT eq.eq_week
FROM eq
GROUP BY eq.eq_week
PIVOT CONVERT(INTEGER, eq_mag);
```

Comment: Max, I tried to execute the query. However, MySQL displays 'SQL syntax error near 'transform count(usaeq.eq_time) as count_occur
select usaeq.eq_time
group by usaeq.eq_time
pivot convert(integer, eq_mag);'

Comment: As I am working with sql I do not know how to convert this for myself,  sorry

Answer (score 0):

It's not all that complicated. In fact, it's a fairly standard pattern found in a lot of queries. Just a series of CASE statements with SUMs for each group you want. Here's a simple version based on the data you give. I've even added extra groups.

```
WITH usaeq( eq_time, eq_mag )AS(
    SELECT '2015-02-19', 0.74 UNION ALL
    SELECT '2015-02-19', 0.55 UNION ALL
    SELECT '2015-02-19', 1.01 UNION ALL
    SELECT '2015-02-19', 4.60 UNION ALL
    SELECT '2015-02-19', 1.44 UNION ALL
    SELECT '2015-02-19', 1.60 UNION ALL
    SELECT '2015-02-19', 0.57 UNION ALL
    SELECT '2015-02-19', 0.71 UNION ALL
    SELECT '2015-02-19', 0.41 UNION ALL
    SELECT '2015-02-19', 2.37
)
SELECT  DatePart( WW, eq_time ) Week,
        Sum( case when eq_mag >= 0.0 and eq_mag < 1 then 1 else 0 end ) as "0-0.99",
        Sum( case when eq_mag >= 1.0 and eq_mag < 2 then 1 else 0 end ) as "1-1.99",
        Sum( case when eq_mag >= 2.0 and eq_mag < 3 then 1 else 0 end ) as "2-2.99",
        Sum( case when eq_mag >= 3.0 and eq_mag < 4 then 1 else 0 end ) as "3-3.99",
        Sum( case when eq_mag >= 4.0 and eq_mag < 5 then 1 else 0 end ) as "4-4.99",
        Sum( case when eq_mag >= 5.0 and eq_mag < 6 then 1 else 0 end ) as "5-5.99"
FROM    usaeq
group by DatePart( WW, eq_time );
```

Comment: Thank you for the query. The MySQL on my machine is not supporting the above query. It displays error
`Error Code: 1305. FUNCTION usaeq.DatePart does not exist`
and
`Error Code 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for SELECT '2015-02-19', 0.74 UNION ALL 
SELECT at line 1`

Comment: My apologies. I wrote the above using SQL Server. Check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/82271/1 for the MySQL equivalent.

Comment: I will use your query in my next project. Thanks TommCatt.